# "An item with the same key has already been added" exception is thrown when TryGetValue is used to prevent that

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a method with the following lines:

```
lock (_dictionaryLock)
            {
                foreach (SomeObject obj in objs)
                {
                    if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(obj.Id, out DateTimeOffset value))
                    {
                        if (DateTimeOffset.Compare(value, obj.Time) != 0)
                        {
                            _dictionary[obj.Id] = obj.Time;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _dictionary.Add(obj.Id, obj.Time);
                    }
                }
            }
```

It still throws the "An item with the same key has already been added" exception. Since I am already  checking TryGetValue, this exception should not happen. obj.Id is another class where I override the Equals and GetHashCode methods but I couldnt come up with a unit test to reproduce the exception and I tried all the possibilities. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Possibly you made a mistake in those overrides of Equals and GetHashCode.

Comment: It seems you are doing multithreaded code. Is it possible that you failed to protect all access to the dictionary? It could explain your difficulty to reproduce as it may be linked to race conditions.

Comment: You are not locking the object objs so items could be added in the middle of your code posted.  You should combine the read and write code in one method so you are not reading and writing at the same time.

Comment: Can you post the whole class? It's not possible from this to tell if another method modifies the dictionary.